# Materialize datepicker looking odd in Meteor

Tags: meteor, materialize

With the Materialize package (materialize:materialize) in Meteor I'm using the datepicker that's getting some of the dates buggered up on the left.

On page render I've got:

```
Template.clientEntry.onRendered(function() {
  $('select').material_select();
  $('.datepicker').pickadate({
    selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
    selectYears: 40 // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="input-field col s2">
     <label class="active">Birth Date</label>
     <input type="date" class="datepicker" id="birthdate-demo">
</div>
```

When the field is clicked, it renders as below. It functions fine, but it's not looking great. Something I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was numbering my table rows in CSS by default. The calendar on the date picker must be a table, so it was trying to number each row. I wasn't able to alter the CSS on the date picker in Meteor, so I had to refactor all my tables to default to go without numbering and add a class to number them.